# How to trigger a OOZIE workflow from HUE console

Tags: hadoop, hue, cloudera-cdh

I want to trigger the OOZIE workflow with the job.properties from HUE console, can anyone suggest me how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The best if you have the workflow.xml and an optional job.properties is to use Hue's File Browser: http://gethue.com/hadoop-tutorial-submit-any-oozie-jobs-directly-from/